# Как запустить команду из другой директории?

Tags: linux, терминал

В домашней директории находится папка с установленной программой `/home/user/programm`, которая запускается из самой директории так:

```
user@ubuntu:~/programm$ ./programm
```

Как мне запустить программу сразу из домашней директории?

Comment: `./programm/programm`

Comment: `./programm/programm` :)

Answer (score 1):

Находясь в домашней директории:

```
./programm/programm
```

Comment: ./ не нужно, путь считается от текущего.